# Sending and receiving strings over socket

Tags: python, sockets, encoding, floating-point, typeerror

I receive and send data(coordinates) over the tcp/ip socket, 
the connections is cameraPC-> laptop-> robot.
The string i receive is: DET4 1 X:75.84 Y:60.96 VINKEL:208.80 LUTANDE:0

I take the X and Y coordinates out, those are the data that i want to send to the robot. I'm new to coding, but from what i've understood it's not possible to send floats, strings, or lists via sockets. Which leaves me to bytes. But when converting to bytes like `SR.send(bytes(CamX, 'utf-8'))` I' actually sending b'CamX'.  But with the b prefix, the robot won't read it correctly.

I've talked to the robot company and they suggested `SR.send("(" + str(CamX) + ", " + str(CamY) + ")")` , they have tried this with success. But I get the error "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Program so far:

```
#RECEIVING DATA FROM CAMERA#
import socket
host= "192.168.1.10"
port= 3000

print("start");
S = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
S.connect((host,port))
received = str(S.recv(1024), "utf-8")
print(received);
S.close()

#CONVERTING DATA TO X,Y COORDINATES#

CamX=received[9:14]
CamY=received[17:23]

CamX=float(CamX)
CamY=float(CamY)

print('X:', CamX)
print('Y:', CamY)


#SENDING DATA TO ROBOT#
host2="192.168.1.5"
print("start");
SR = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
SR.bind((host2,port))
SR.listen(5)
conn, addr=SR.accept()
print("Connected by ",addr)
SR.sendto(CamX,host2)
```

EDIT, solved: 
Fixed it by adding
 `CamPos= '('+str(CamX) +','+str(CamY)+',0.2,0.01,3.14,0.01)'` to the converting part,
 and with `conn.send(CamPos.encode('utf-8'))` to send the data. 
Not sure why it works now, since I think I've tried this before.

Comment: Maybe Python 2 versus Python 3 issues?  Try in Python 2.

Comment: Fixed it. Uppdated the post with the fix